# How to use mqttjs to publish to iot shadow topic?

Tags: mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I am using MQTTJS client to publish and subscribe to my IoT topics from react application.

I tried to use MQTTJS to get/update my AWS device shadow but I can't send or receive anything from my device shadow.
here is my code

```
client.publish('$aws/things/things/deviceId/shadow/get', {});
```

Comment: The topic is incorrect. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html

Comment: @cementblocks I updated the topic but I still go no response

Comment: Show your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

If you also using cognito, you can connect, subscribe, and publish topics using this framework:
https://github.com/jimmyn/aws-mqtt-client

or just use MQTTJS

Either way I would check to make sure you have created a iot policy to allow access to the topics your trying to publish to.
As seen here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policies.html

You'll also need to make sure you have created a role with an IAM policy that allows access to iot; that can be attached to whatever credentials you used to auth the MQTTclient.

Comment: I can publish /subscribe to other IoT topics, but not to device shadow under the same account. I double checked my policy/role and in I have full IoT access